# Listing items by category in a multidimensional array - jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am trying to list my items by category so what I want to show is something like this.

Category A

Item 1

Item 2

Category B

Item 1

Item 3

Item 4

Category C

Item 3

Item 4

This is the array I have and how should I print my categories and list the items under?  `$scope.categoryArray = [ {name:"Item 1", on: false, subcategory:"Category A"}, {name:"Item 2", on: false, subcategory:"Category A"}, 
    {name:"Item 1", on:false, subcategory:"Category B"}, {name:"Item 3", on: false, subcategory:"Category B"}, 
    {name:"Item 4", on: false, subcategory:"Category B"}, {name:"Item 3", on: false, subcategory:"Category C"}, 
    {name:"Item 4", on: false, subcategory:"Category C"}];`

Thanks in advance for your input!

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("c", function($scope) {
  $scope.categoryArray = [{
    name: "Item 1",
    on: false,
    subcategory: "Category A"
  }, {
    name: "Item 2",
    on: false,
    subcategory: "Category A"
  }, {
    name: "Item 1",
    on: false,
    subcategory: "Category B"
  }, {
    name: "Item 3",
    on: false,
    subcategory: "Category B"
  }, {
    name: "Item 4",
    on: false,
    subcategory: "Category B"
  }, {
    name: "Item 3",
    on: false,
    subcategory: "Category C"
  }, {
    name: "Item 4",
    on: false,
    subcategory: "Category C"
  }];
  $scope.array = [];

  for (var item in $scope.categoryArray) {
    var obj = $scope.array[$scope.categoryArray[item].subcategory];
    if (!obj)
      $scope.array[$scope.categoryArray[item].subcategory] = [];
    $scope.array[$scope.categoryArray[item].subcategory].push($scope.categoryArray[item].name);

  }
  var str = "";
  for (var cat in $scope.array) {
    str += cat + "</br>";
    for (var item in $scope.array[cat]) {
      str += $scope.array[cat][item] + "</br>";
    }
  }
  $("#content").html(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="c" id="content"></div>
```

Comment: This is great.  Thanks for the answer.